# In PHP, can I get MySQL to rollback a transaction if I disconnect without committing, rather than commit it?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

If I run the following PHP, I would expect no value to be inserted into the test table, because I have a transaction that I haven't committed:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","test","test");
mysql_select_db("test");
mysql_query("begin transaction;");
mysql_query("insert into Test values (1);") or die("insert error: ". mysql_errror());
die('Data should not be commited\n');
mysql_query("commit;"); // never occurs because of the die()
```

But instead it seems to commit anyway. Is there a way to turn off this behaviour without turning off autocommit for the PHP that doesn't use transactions elsewhere on the site?

Comment: On my install of MySQL, the query "BEGIN TRANSACTION" gives the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'transaction' at line 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mysql_query('BEGIN'). The SQL "BEGIN TRANSACTION" is not valid (and in fact mysql_query is returning false on that query, which means there is an error). It's not working because you never start a transaction.

Comment: Whoops! I meant to type "start transaction", not "begin transaction", and when I fix that it works.

Comment: It's *always* something simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to start a transaction is:

```
START TRANSACTION
```

The feature you are talking about *is* AUTOCOMMIT. If you don't want it, you'll have to disable it:

```
SET autocommit = 0
```

The reference can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html

I also recommend that you test the return value of all mysql_...() functions. You cannot assume that they'll always run successfully.

Comment: Yeah. In production code I do test the return value of mysql functions, but this was just a silly test script to proove to a collegue that to use transactions we wouldn't need to go through the code and add hundreds of rollback statements wherever there was an error. The existing die statements would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the transaction will not be rolled back. It is the responsibility of your application code to decide how to handle this error, whether that's trying again, or rolling back.

If you want automatic rollback, that is also explained in the manual:

```
The current transaction is not rolled back. To have the entire transaction roll back, start the server with the `--innodb_rollback_on_timeout` option.
```